# Submitting "ps" across multiple servers, output going to one text file

Tags: ssh, scripting, ps

I'm trying to build a script that'll output all defunct processes across 66 redhat boxes to a single text file. I understand the principles of doing this on one box, but I'm not sure how to shoehorn that process into something that'll run on one box, but query several boxes.

So, I've found this little script:

```
for host in $(cat hosts.txt); do ssh "$host" "$command" >"output.$host"; done
```

I understand that I could essentially submit `ps -ef | grep "defunct"` as the `$command`, but I think any output file I create will be dropped onto the host it's running on.

I need to make this run from one box, storing the output on that one box, but containing the information for the other 65 boxes?

I believe we have passwordless ssh in place. My knowledge of Unix is sort of intermediate, I know bits of it because I'm using SAS.

Comment: what your asking is something quiet common with tool like saltstack puppet chef or ansible. Those tool are meant to simplyfy and centralized the configuration of multiple server. But this is cleary not a short term solution as they are all quiet complicated on the first look. If you need more of those kind of scrit you should take a look

Comment: The redirection happens on the calling machine, not on the remote machine, so the result file will be local. Also, the `grep` does not need to run remotely.

Comment: See [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for why the answers you receive use `while` instead of `for`.

Comment: I'd search for a status containing `Z`, not the word "defunct" in the argument list, because not all implementations of `ps` use this format for zombies.

Comment: One huge benefit of using salt-ssh or fabric to do this is the built in support for parallelism. Running this on 66 remote machines in serial will take a while. Running it on say 12-15 machines at a time will take much less time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redirection happens on the calling machine, not on the remote machine, so the result file will be local. Also, the `grep` does not need to run remotely:

```
while read -r host; do
    ssh "$host" ps -ef | grep "defunct" >"output.$host"
done <hosts.txt
```

This executes `ps -ef` on each host and `grep` will extract the `defunct` lines of output.  The `grep` will run locally, not remotely.  The result file, likewise, is created locally.

If you want a single output file:

```
while read -r host; do
    ssh "$host" ps -ef | grep "defunct"
done <hosts.txt >output.txt
```

Or even (for a single invocation of `grep`)

```
while read -r host; do
    ssh "$host" ps -ef 
done <hosts.txt | grep "defunct" >output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed response. I'm trying to use it, but I've got another two issues.When (if) the loop runs, I receive the "Host not known" error message. If I literally just type "ssh hostname" it works, but it doesn't recognise the same hostname from the text file I'm feeding to it.



Also, running the command now places me at a ">" cursor and I have to CTRL C out of it.



This isn't working at all I'm afraid.
`while read -r host; do ssh "$host" < done < /dir1/dir2/known_hosts.txt`

Comment: @Dan `< done <` is wrong and you're missing the `ps` command. See my answer.

Comment: Sorry, in my haste to remove any corporate information I included the extra < by mistake. The submitted code doesn't contain the < before the word done. Also I'm leaving off the ps command for now, the less to debug the better.

The first issue was being caused by me submitting the entire command on one line. I've split it back to three lines and it loops fine, but, I'm given the "Name or service not known" error. It actually reads like this (where "servername" is the host I'm trying to connect to):
`: Name or service not _knownname_ servername`

Comment: The word "knownname" suggests to me that "name" isn't being provided properly but I have no idea how to get around that. I'm literally just submitting three server names to this loop, there's no other data.

Comment: @Dan Your input file has one server name per line?

Comment: So - further update. "knownname" is a non-issue, it's because BOTH error messages `ssh: Could not resolve hostname` AND `Name or service not known` are being shown on top of each other on the same line.

Each server name is written on a new line. It should be one continuous column of servers. It seems, for some reason, when ssh is invoked via this loop, it's breaking the ability to resolve the server name.

I've just added the -n flag to ssh but no help.

Comment: I've just limited the file to one server name and submitted `ssh cat /dir1/dir2/known_hosts.txt` and it won't resolve the server name. If I copy the name returned from the error message and manually ssh to it, it works.

Comment: @Dan Are you editing the server list on Windows? It may in that case have trailing carriage returns on each line...

Comment: I was originally created in windows, FTP'd across and since then it's been edited in VI. I've ensured through VI that there's no illegal characters. That did cross my mind though.

Comment: Another update. CRLF was found and removed after further searches and a very simple ssh cat command worked. I'll submit via the loop and see what happens.

Comment: Script doesn't work as intended, output file is 0bytes. I've reverted to the script in the OP and it works perfectly. Next steps now are to get around the "The authenticity of host can't be established." messages which will prevent this job from being batched up into SAS.